# Pegar no MainActivity eventos no App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Tenho isso no meu App.xaml.cs

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
{                    
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
};
```

Quando eu receber mensagens, ou seja, ter alguma coisa no p.data, como eu disparo no MainActivity meu badge?

No OnCreate do Activity eu tenho

```
badge = new Badge();
```

E necessito criar agora um método ou outra coisa para disparar o contador do badge, tipo assim:

```
Contador++;
badge.count(Contador);
```

Não estou conseguindo pegar nada no App a partir do MainActivity e nem o contrário, mesmo adicionando as devidas referências.

Aquela lambda está dentro do construtor da classe App.xaml.cs.